# Adding a string to vsnprintf

Tags: c

I have a following function:

```
void printerror(char *fmt, ...) {
    char string[256];
    va_list str;
    va_start(str, fmt);
    vsnprintf(string, 256, fmt, str);
    va_end(str);
    }
```

I want to add an const char at the beginning of the string variable in the vsnprintf. How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put a char at the beginning of a string:

```
string[0] = 'X';
```

Then fill the remainder of the string. Its address is 1 greater:

```
vsnprintf(&string[1], 255, fmt, str);
```

or (which is the same)

```
vsnprintf(string + 1, 255, fmt, str);
```

Here I am using 255 instead of 256 (bugfix, noted by Andrew Henle) as the maximum length of the string to fill, because one byte is already filled.

Comment: You'd also want to change the second argument to `vsnprintf()` to reflect the fact that the buffer is partially used.

Comment: Thanks. how to do if its an char array?